# Core jQuery not working in Bootstrap theme

Tags: 8, javascript, bootstrap-theme

I am using Bootstrap 3 subtheme and Drupal 8. For some reason when I add the dependency core/jquery it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
mysubtheme:
  css:
    theme:
      css/slippry.css: {}
    header: true
    js:
      js/slippry.js: {}
  dependencies:
      - core/jquery
```

The only way I can get jquery to load is when I put the jquery.min.js URL into my page.html.twig file.

Answer (score 1):

Yaml is heavily indentation oriented.

There are yaml validators like: [YAMLlint](http://www.yamllint.com). It will also the intendation for you. But not the wrongly set header option.

You have two indents (spaces) to much before the dash, plus js: needs to be upped too. Also the header property is set wrong, check the [docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) - if you want the js in the header, it needs its own library definition:

```
mysubtheme:
  css:
    theme:
      css/slippry.css: {}
  js:
    js/slippry.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

> This will work ! (but is in the footer)

This is how the two library definitions will look like:

```
slippry-css:
  css:
    theme:
      css/slippry.css: {}
```

and

```
slippry-js:
  header: true
  js:
    js/slippry.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

**You'll need then to add both libraries!**

Maybe this will work too:

```
mysubtheme:
  header: true
  css:
    theme:
      css/slippry.css: {}
  js:
    js/slippry.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

To debug your libraries, use [libraries_ui](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries_ui)

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it still isn't working.. :(

Comment: Sorry .. js: was also wrongly intended (see my edit). You need to rebuild the caches too !

Comment: You should run it through a yaml linter - it will tell you if there are errors in spacing.

Comment: I did use YAMLlint to do it but something is not right. This is the website: http://outdoorsfinland.fi/drupal/

Comment: Pls review my edited answer, you intended also js: and header: wrong

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. Copied straight from yours.

Comment: You can debug with libraries ui or devel. see links in answer

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot on monday. :D Work day is over for today.